# Converting word doc to PNG without compression

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some Word documents that are drawings with captions, that I would like to convert to PNG format.  The problem I ran into was that the file size went from about 750 Kb in the original Word doc to 27 Kb in the PNG format.  Is there any way to prevent compression in the word to PNG conversion?

Thankyou for any answer?

Comment: Why does the file size matter? PNG conversion is lossless so all the information is still there.

Comment: The size of the object inside the word document is much smaller than the word document itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use a web-based Word document viewer (such as [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)) to present the document's pages as images in your web browser. Zoom to the desired size, then save the images.